Which of these 4 statements about sets A and B are equivalent?
Which of these 4 statements about sets A and B are equivalent?:
(1) A $\cap$ C $\subseteq$ B $\cap$ C for all C
(2) A $\subseteq$ B
(3) A $\cup$ C $\subseteq$ B $\cup$ C for all C
(4) A \ B = $\emptyset$
(2) and (4) are obviously equivalent
I think (2) and (3) are also equivalent because x $\in$ A $\cup$ C $\iff$ x $\in$ A V x $\in$ C $\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A. Similarly for x $\in$ B $\cup$ C. So A $\subseteq$ B.
But I'm not 100% sure about whether (1) is equivalent to any of the rest. I feel like it is because if I rewrite it into (x $\in$ A $\cap$ C $\rightarrow$ x $\in$ B $\cap$ C) $\iff$ (x $\in$ A $\land$  x $\in$ C $\rightarrow$ x $\in$ B $\land$  x $\in$ C)
But can I conclude that x $\in$ A $\rightarrow$ x $\in$ B?
Thank you in advance for all your help.

Please use MathJax also for arrows. Here is a
tutorial.

For (1) to be true, one of the $C$ to consider is the empty set, and so $A\cap B\subseteq B\cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

I thought of that too but then how can I prove (1) and (2) are equivalent for all C?

So (1) and (2) are not equivalent. A counterexample $A = B = {0}$, (1) is false (e.g. when $C=\emptyset$), while (2) is true.

If $C=\emptyset $ what does 1) imply?  And what does 2) imply?

Sorry I made a typo. (1) is A $\cap$ C $\subseteq$ B $\cap$ C

You correctly state that $(2)$ is equivalent to $(4)$.
Let us show that $(2)$ is equivalent to $(3)$. First, why $(2)$ implies $(3)$. Take any $C$. Let $x$ be in $A\cup C$. Then, by definition of union, $x\in A$ or $x\in C$. Since $A$ is a subset of $B$, we get that $x\in B$ or $x\in C$. By definition of union, this means that $x\in B\cup C$.
Now let us show that $(3)$ implies $(2)$. Just take $C=\emptyset$. Then $A\cup C \subseteq B\cup C$ becomes $A\subseteq B$.
$(1)$ is also equivalent to $(2)$. Why does $(2)$ imply $(1)$? Take any $C$. Now let $x$ be in $A\cap C$. By definition of intersection, it means that $x \in A$ and $x\in C$. Since $A$ is a subset of $B$, $x$ is in $B$ and in $C$. Hence, by definition of intersection, $x$ is in $B\cap C$.
To see that $(1)$ implies $(2)$ take $C=A\cup B$. Then $A\cap C \subseteq B\cap C$ turns into $A\subseteq B$.

Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.
